# I tried to make a slideshow for images from an images folder with python using OpenCv but it doesn't work with me

Tags: python, file, path

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from math import ceil
import os

dst = "C:\OpencvPython\frames\slide"       # Images destination
images = os.listdir(dst)    # Get their names in a list
length = len(images)

result = np.zeros((360,360,3), np.uint8)        # Image window 
of size (360, 360)
i = 1

a = 1.0     # alpha
b = 0.0     # beta
img = cv2.imread(dst + images[i])
img = cv2.resize(img, (360, 360))

# Slide Show Loop
while(True):

if(ceil(a)==0):
    a = 1.0
    b = 0.0
    i = (i+1)%length    # Getting new image from directory
    img = cv2.imread(dst + images[i])
    img = cv2.resize(img, (360, 360))

a -= 0.01
b += 0.01

# Image Transition from one to another
result = cv2.addWeighted(result, a, img, b, 0)
cv2.imshow("Slide Show", result)
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
if key==ord('q'):
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> [ WARN:0@0.007] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('C:/OpencvPython/frames/slidedownload (2).jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4052: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the path, you can replace `img = cv2.imread(dst + images[i])` with
`img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(dst, images[i]))`

Using `+` operator will directly add 2nd sting to the base path, for example if `dst = "C:\OpencvPython\frames\slide"` and `images[i] = "img1.png"` then `dst + images[i]` would become `"C:\OpencvPython\frames\slideimg1.png"` hence leading to file not found error while `os.path.join` will generate correct path.